# Kubernetes: exec via WebSocket API; close stdin?

Tags: kubernetes

Within an already established WebSocket connection to the `/exec` API endpoint of the Kubernetes API server, is it possible to somehow close stdin without completely closing the WebSocket connection? This would be required for piping data into a remotely executed command and then saying `EOF`.

I tried sending `[0]` (no data on stdin), but that didn't work. I can't find anything related to that in the source code as well.

Comment: Do you use native client from https://github.com/kubernetes-client ? Could you please share some code examples and error messages?

Comment: Does websockets work for any other kube-apiserver API?

Comment: I'm using [this](https://github.com/abonas/kubeclient) client. The official clients from github.com/kubernetes-client don't seem to have implemented exec at all (at least I don't see it in the go client). [kubectl implements it over SPDY](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/cmd/exec/exec.go#L105), but I have read in multiple locations that this should be replaced by WebSocket in the long term.

Comment: @AlfredKrohmer did you find a solution to this problem finally?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Well, after 1 year. I'm now spending 4+ hours on the issue and could not find anything. Source code is almost impossible to understand and there is no documentation. I will share if I can find anything...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently doing this is not supported, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89899. Pretty crazy that the  SPDY protocol has been deprecated for years (that's how `kubectl` accomplishes this) and the WebSocket protocol can't do something so basic.

The best workaround I can think of is to execute the desired command within a shell, and then use shell tricks to tell the shell when you're done sending input.

For example, you could use the "<< trick": set the command to be `bash -c "my_command << EOF"`, and then the shell will read from `stdin` until it sees  EOF. (Make sure to shell-escape your command and arguments if necessary.)